# Client to interface with Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Are there any free clients that interface with a Microsoft SQL Server located on a remote server?

Comment: What do you mean "client"?

Comment: @joeqwerty, GUI interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the free product from Microsoft: SQL-Server Management Studio Express

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

Every windows has a driver and then there is the some open source library talking the wire level  protocol.

All those are, from a SQL Server's point of view, clients.

One level higher you have TONS of programming langauges that can handle databases.

Comment: Yeah I'm using C# to interface with the database, no problems there, just wanted a little visual GUI to take a look at table structure and what not.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a product called "Toad".  I believe they have a free version.  It also supports multiple platforms as well.

I don't use it myself, as I only have to manage one platform.  However, I have seen numerous cow-orkers using it and they had good things to say about it.